# Why is the meaning of "rustle up" different to "rustle"?

Tags: word-difference

According to Oxford Dictionary, 'rustle' means to make a soft, muffled crackling sound like that caused by the movement of dry leaves or paper.

The same dictionary says that 'rustle up' means to produce something quickly when it is needed.

My question is, why is the meaning so different just by adding 'up' after 'rustle'?

Comment: I hope someone will provide a better answer, but I'll give a two-word hint to get you started: [*phrasal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) [*verbs*](http://www.englishpage.com/prepositions/phrasaldictionary.html).

Comment: In English, the smaller the word, the more superpowers it has.  :)

Comment: Although the below answers do give some suggestions, this is probably one of those infuriating times in the English language where 'because it does' is the correct answer

Comment: Here is a site that gives some good etymological history of the phrase "rustle up": http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/05/rustle-up.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Up" when yoked to a verb conveys the idea of "completion" or "completeness" although most speakers aren't consciously aware of this aspect of the resulting verb, and may think in terms of space and direction (ascent, rising) if asked to explain the verb.

We can **size up** a person or a situation.   To assess the person *from head to toe* or to assess the situation in its entirety.

We can **rustle up** some grub.   To put a few ingredients together hastily to *produce a meal*.

We can **tie** a package **up**.  To *fasten* it *securely*, not incompletely so that it could work itself loose during shipping and handling.

She rudely told me  to **shut up**.  To close my mouth completely and *to keep it closed* (no more words from me).

He **walked up** to the girl.   He walked not just towards her but *all the way* to where she was, so that they were face-to-face and within normal speaking distance.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I think it might *stir **up*** a bit of controversy if we *start **up*** a list of all phrasal verbs based on ***up***, and count them up to see what proportion have connotations of "completion". That's just 33% in this comment.

Comment: I think of *stir up* as taking an action that results in something being set in motion. The "yield" of our action is the controversy, I suspect some would say that we're getting it going, so it's inceptive aspect, but I think of it as succeeding in getting it going, completive.  If we manage to start the car up, we get the engine to turn over. Completive. If we count them up, we run through the entire list of items. Completive.

Comment: Hold up! So even if that makes you *pause* in this line of thinking, you'll still say the first two words here are "completive" because they imply success in stalling it? I don't know if I can put up with that! :)

Comment: "Hold up!" means "Come to a complete halt!", right?  It doesn't mean merely "reduce your speed".

Comment: *Put up with* is murkier. :)

Comment: Dang! I suppose if I say I give up, you'll just say that proves your point. Or would it be [a turn up for the books](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/turn-up-for-the-books.html) (an expression I've used all my life without ever knowing the origin until now - isn't Google *wonderful!* :)

Comment: There are also literal (non-aspectual) meanings. To **put someone up** for the night probably referred originally to giving them lodgings in sleeping quarters upstairs. So it won't always be the case that "up" conveys the idea of  *completely* or *completion*.

Comment: I think in *rustle up, gather up, pile up, sweep up* etc., the (usually optional) preposition probably owes more to *height* (of a resultant figurative or literal "heap"). I think you're probably right that *most speakers aren't consciously aware* of the semantic contribution made by any given preposition in the context of many (most?) phrasal verbs. It'd be kinda interesting to know whether there's sufficient consistency for it to be useful to nns to take conscious note of "likely" connotations.

Comment: With *pile up* a literal meaning is most likely, and maybe too with "sweep up", though it's possible to understand it as *completional* or *attaintive*. (I just made those words up.)  *Tidy up* means to attain neatness, to make things neat, and that's how I understand *sweep up* -- get rid of the dirt on the floor, to make the floor clean. "Clean" is an attained status;"The car's almost clean, dad.". To *gather up* means to bring together (and things are not together when they're *almost* together).

Answer (score 3):

The relevant sense comes under OED's definition section II, headed ...

> *To be active, to make efforts; to acquire or gather something energetically*

...which is first recorded in 1835 as *Get up, rouse and rustle about, and get away from these scores*. Interestingly, that's the same year the sense *Of livestock: to search for food, to forage; to graze* was first recorded. The meaning *To round up and steal (cattle, horses, etc.)* wasn't recorded until 1886.

The exact sense *to hunt out; (freq. **in later use**) to put together (a dish or meal). Now usu. with **up**.* is first recorded (somewhat "marginally", I feel) in 1844 as *He nailed my thumb in his jaws, and **rostled** [sic] up a handful of dirt & throwed it in my eyes.* But OED's *next* citation isn't until 1890...

> *I was out one day after antelope (I ‘rustled’ all my meat, except a ham now and then as a luxury)*.

Given that the *surreptitiously steal cattle* sense was already "established" by then, I'm tempted to see that as closer to the intended sense above. But I think it's a good example of a usage showing part of the transition *rustle = make a **quiet** noise* => *[quietly] **gather** together* => *gather together [**food**]*.

Note that OED only says this sense *usually* involves ***up***. So, for example, *I'll [rustle some breakfast](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rustle%20some%20breakfast%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)* isn't actually "wrong" - it's just that most people would usually include the preposition.