# "Google up" meaning

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Can I use the preposition **up** with the verb **google**? I found it only on Urban Dictionary which isn't a very reliable dictionary.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Google%20it%20up):

> **Google up** Informal phrase used to describe performing an Internet search using the Google Search Engine.
> John: "Hey, when was the King Dome imploded?"
> Kristin: "I think it was in 1996."
> John: "Hmmm, I don't think so. **Let's *Google* it *up*!**"

It sounds very natural to say **google up**. Can I use it with the verb **google**? Will it mean the same as **googling**?

Comment: It sounds natural to me but I would also say informal, and "fun", or silly.

Comment: You could compare it with the phrase "mix it up" or "mix it up a little"... it might help to look at that.  It definitely means the same thing as before when you add "up", but I would suggest that it is unclear what the "up" is doing... it sort of has the sense of doing more googling - a more lengthy effort, perhaps.

Comment: This is at the sharp end of the evolution of language. I would probably not use it myself, but would have no trouble understanding it were it said to me. Don't forget that the verb "to google" is itself a neologism, and widespread usage has made it an addition to the English language. Hence whether it is "correct" or not is purely a matter of what sticks.

Comment: Surely it's used in a similar sense to 'look up', 'dial up' etc.

Comment: I googled it up. It was March 26, 2000  (and it's Kingdome, one word)

Comment: Related: [Why is the meaning of “rustle up” different to “rustle”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/65738/9161)

Comment: Related:[Is the word "UP" a signal of the informality?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183096/is-the-word-up-a-signal-of-the-informality)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to add "up" after a verb and when not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10725/when-to-add-up-after-a-verb-and-when-not)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in an informal sense.  It assumes "google" is a verb, which I think is reasonably accepted by now.